# Why does System.out.print cause autoflush?

Tags: java, buffer, system.out

System.out is a PrintStream object. I read the documentation on PrintStream. What I don't get is why System.out.print causes the buffer to be flushed? Shouldn't that happen only for println?

Comment: Relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402529/will-javas-system-out-print-buffer-forever-until-println

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't that happen only for println?

The Javadoc doesn't say when it *won't* be flushed. And it says it *will* be flushed on a `println()` *or a newline*.

Comment: I've been experimenting with this in NetBeans. And apparently it does not seem to matter. println seems to be flushing even when autoflush is turned off. Here is my small code:

public class C{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Test.txt"));
      ps.println("VinDiesel!");   
      //ps.flush();
      
      ps.close();
        
    }
}

Comment: @Chatterjee I don't see what that test is supposed to prove. It doesn't use System out, and closing the stream flushes it.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that just now. I would rather rephrase that as println not working for an ordinary PrintStream object. However, let's say I try to read from that same file before closing it. I still find that the string has been flushed. Am I seriously getting something wrong here? Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @Chatterjee It works as expected for me, i.e. no flush after print(). I don't know what you're doing so I can't comment further.

Comment: Thanks anyways. I guess it's probably implementation dependent. I got the same result with Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of repeating the *facts* that have already been noted, let me try to interpret the doc a little differently...

It seems that it's only at PrintBuffer **creation time** (that is, during constructor invocation) that the autoFlush behavior of a PrintStream can be set.

Also, as you've pointed out, the documentation states that, when calling any of the various public PrintBuffer constructors, not specifying the autoflush state will result in a non-autoflushing PrintStream being created.

However, in the System.out case, **you** are not calling the construtor for the PrintBuffer.  The java.lang.System class instantiates the "out" PrintStream on VM startup.  That means that, when you request the PrintStream object that the System object stores in its "out" field, you have no idea which constructor was called, and therefore no idea of the autoflush state of the stream that gets handed to you when you ask for it.

I agree, it would have been really nice if the doc for java.lang.System specified that the stream contained in its "out" field has its autoflush behavior set to true.  But that's not a "requirement," any more than I'm required to document whether the JButton returned from my  (hypothetical) myCrazyPanel.getTheChangeColorsButton() is enabled or disabled.  Yeah, buttons are enabled **by default**, but you're not allowed to complain if the JButton is disabled.  Same thing here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Bob. I'm now trying to check whether println autoflushes in case of an ordinary PrintStream object

Answer (score 0):

You want the buffer to be flushed when you call System.out.print() because you want it to be printed. When I call print, I want it to print something. If it didn't flush, it would just remain in the buffer and I wouldn't see anything.

Check out flush [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29).

Basically it's a guarantee that it'll get printed immediately.

Comment: I do understand that. However, I quote the following from the Java documentation for PrintStream:

"Optionally, a PrintStream can be created so as to flush automatically; this means that the flush method is automatically invoked after a byte array is written, one of the println methods is invoked, or a newline character or byte ('\n') is written. "

It is not stated here that a call to print will result in the buffer getting flushed. Thats's what I am saying