# Evaluation order of expressions with read-line in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am running the following code snippet:

```
(print "Enter something:")
(let [entry (read-line)]
  (println "You entered" entry)
)
```

I expect to see the following type of interaction:

```
Enter something:abc
You entered abc
```

Instead, I see:

```
abc
Enter something:You entered abc
```

Why is user input requested first, even though the print comes first in the code? I tried Googling around, but from what I can tell, evaluation order should be what I would expect coming from a Java/Python background. Is this the expected behavior of the code?

Comment: Aha--side effects. Sorry for the duplicate question, I'm still getting used to the terminology.

Comment: Java flushes stdout on `\n`. You will need to forcibly flush the buffer if you want the output exactly (read consistently, as you have no control over it) as you have written it in your example, or you could add a `\n` using `(println ...)` or `(print ... "\n")`.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402529/will-javas-system-out-print-buffer-forever-until-println

Comment: No need to apologise for a duplicate question such as this, Max. We do not go through the dictionary weeding out synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pasting my comment over into a real answer.

Java flushes stdout on `\n`. You will need to forcibly flush the buffer if you want the output exactly (read consistently, as you have no control over it) as you have written it in your example, or you could add a `\n` using `(println ...)` or `(print ... "\n")`.

See: [Will Java's System.out.print() buffer forever until println()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402529/will-javas-system-out-print-buffer-forever-until-println)